# Can't save remarks: error states that title and code section are missing

Tags: bug, documentation

I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow. I am having a hell of a time understanding how to use the site.

I attempted to post a new topic in the PHP section, I filled out the introduction and a code sample. Submitted it. Then I decided to add some information to the remarks section. After filling it out, I try to submit it for review and I get little red error boxes at the title and code sample sections saying that I must add a title and a code sample to save my remark. The title and code section are already filled out and visible on the page.

Am I doing something wrong?